# Qt Creator: distribute an app

Tags: qt, qt-creator, distribution

I'm new to Qt - please, can someone tell me how to build an app so I can run in on other computer without Qt?

I downloaded Qt for Mac, I can run the provided examples. Now I would like to distribute the resulting application in a self-contained package so that users don't have to install or do anything. What do I have to do?

I have the very latest 5.0.1 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is documented in Qt's documentation:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/deployment.html

Note that currently, a static build of Qt 5.0 does not work. (4.8 works.)

Comment: If static building does not work, I have to use frameworks, right? Do I have to manually copy all the "components" (QtCore, QtGui, ...) into the app bundle? I was hoping that Qt Creator could be of some help here, isn't there simpler way than the one in the above link? The article does not mention Creator at all...

Comment: @EcirHana Creator can't do that. Qt 4 has a tool called "macdeployqt" that takes care of creating an app bundle that includes everything you need. But AFAIK it doesn't work anymore with Qt 5. You can use frameworks or simple dylibs. It's up to you. Frameworks are easier to work with though.